# Deep Copying in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, deep-copy

I am from `Swift` and `Python` backgrounds and I have a problem which I would expect an easy answer.

I have a custom class named `Event` and want to deep copy it. From related questions (if I understood right) - there is no inbuilt way to do this in Kotlin. There were suggestions to use Java's functions in Kotlin but since I don't know Java, I prefer to do in another way if possible.

One way to do is in `Event` class:

```
fun copy() : Event {
    val event = Event()
    event.property1 = this.property1
    event.property2 = this.property2
    // and same goes for all other properties
    return event
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant and intuitive way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data class`es which have built-in `copy` methods in conjunction with immutable objects (so a deep copy is the same as a shallow copy). If you can't use immutable objects you're left with the alternative you presented in your question, there is no other way to do so. Another thing which you can keep in mind is that Kotlin has its own persistent data structures [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable) which is a great solution for this problem!

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your answer. Yes, I need to use mutable objects but thanks a lot about mentioning the library - I didn't know it and will definitely look into it!

Comment: I've been using that lib for a while now and it is awesome!